# Retry try/catch on promise catch

Tags: node.js, firebase, try-catch, firebase-admin

I am trying to run a script with the firebase admin sdk that is looping through all my users with `listUsers()` and I am handling it like so:

```
admin.auth().listUsers(batch, nextPageToken)
    .then(function(listUsersResult) {
        // process successful results
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // log the error
    });
```

Every now and then the call to `listUsers` itself fails with error `Error: www.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.`

I catch the error, but my script will not continue after this.
I have used `retry` before in this situation, but am wondering if or how I could continue from the same batch/token of users that I am on without having to restart my `listUsers` loop. Maybe I am missing something really easy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Promise retries until success/failure with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444601/promise-retries-until-success-failure-with-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i got you right.
You want to retry on a error with same arguments ?

Manually you would do that like this:

```
function fun(batch, nextPageToken, retries = 5) {
  return admin
    .auth()
    .listUsers(batch, nextPageToken)
    .then(listUsersResult => {
      // process successful results
    })
    .catch(error => {
      if (err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT' && retries > 0) {
        const turnsLeft = retries - 1;
        return fun(batch, nextPageToken, turnsLeft);
      }
      throw error;
    });
}
```

But you should use some library for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perfectible base to work from:

```
const withRetry = async (fn, maxAttempts, args, fails=0) => { 
    // fn: function that needs retry on error,
    // maxAttempts: maximum of try attempts
    // args: arguments to be passed to the function it could be a single value, an array or an object it depends on how you use it inside "fn"
    // fails: amount of failed attempts to simulate in order to test the retry mechanism

    const retry = async (attempt=1) => {
        let result = undefined;
        console.log(' • attempt:', attempt); // logs attempt #

        try {
            
            if (attempt <= fails) { // attempt inferior or equals to the defined amount of failures
                result = await fn(args); 
                throw new Error("   Expected to fail"); // force a failure by throwing
            }
                
            else
                result = await fn(args);

        } catch (err) {

            console.log(err.message); 

            if (attempt < maxAttempts) {
                // if you want to define some delay before retrying it goes here
                
                return retry(attempt + 1); // RETURN AND RETRY HERE

            } else if (attempt == maxAttempts) {
                console.log("\n> Error: max attempts have been reached without success");
                return 'err'; // RETURN "err" IN CASE OF MAX ATTEMPT REACHED
            }
                
        }

        console.log('   operation was a success: ');
        return result; // RETURN SUCCESS
    }

    return await retry(); 

}
```

**Below is some code to test it :**

```
async function codeToRetry(args) { // will be used as argument when calling withRetry() 
    let delay;
    
    if (args != null && args.delay)
        delay = args.delay;
    else
        delay = 1000;

    await new Promise(_r => setTimeout(_r, delay));
    return '\x1b[92;1m' + '   some value' + '\x1b[0m';
}



async function test() {
    console.log('> first test:');
    let result = await withRetry(codeToRetry, 5, {delay: 2000}); // will success on first attempt 
    console.log(result);

    console.log('\n> second test:');
    result = await withRetry(codeToRetry, 5, null, 2); // will success on 3rd attempt
    console.log(result);

    console.log('\n> third test:');
    result = await withRetry(codeToRetry, 2, null, 2); // will fail by exceeding the amount of attempts which is 2
    console.log(result);
}

test();
```

It will produce the following output:

```
> first test:
 • attempt: 1
   operation was a success: 
   some value      ------ returned value

> second test:
 • attempt: 1
   Expected to fail
 • attempt: 2
   Expected to fail
 • attempt: 3
   operation was a success: 
   some value      ------ returned value

> third test:
 • attempt: 1
   Expected to fail
 • attempt: 2
   Expected to fail

> Error: max attempts have been reached without success
err                ------ returned value
```